# Denormalizing a relationship through another model in django-denorm

Tags: django, postgresql

Is it possibly to denormalize a multi-level relationship using [django-denorm](https://github.com/initcrash/django-denorm)?

Specifically, I have the following structure:

```
Question --> User --> CustomProfile --> Avatar
```

I want to denormalize the avatar name on the `Question` model. At the moment, I have to traverse through these 4 tables to get that information.

I am using Postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally chaining dependencies works and is the way to handle this situation.

In this case where one model in the chain is not supplied by you, your best option would be to implement your own dependency class similar to those found in:
https://github.com/initcrash/django-denorm/blob/master/denorm/dependencies.py

so you get:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    @denormalized(...)
    @depend_on_related("User")
    @depend_on_indirectly_related("CustomProfile",through="User")
    def avatar(self):
        return self.user.custom_profile.avatar_name

class CustomProfile(models.Model):
    @denormalized(...)
    @depend_on_related("Avatar")
    def avatar_name(self):
        return self.avatar.name
```

this would of course be a welcome patch for django-denorm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to implement that, and contribute back. In the meantime, I have added my own field, and overrid the `save` method of the models in question.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this but you could give this a try:

Cascade the *Depending on related models code* in the [official doc](http://initcrash.github.com/django-denorm/tutorial.html#creating-denormalized-fields-using-callback-functions) across your models i.e `Avatar --> Custom Profile --> User --> Question`

Since it uses triggers internally, it should cascade.

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    # the other fields
    other = models.ForeignKey('SomeOtherModel')

    @denormalized(models.CharField,max_length=100)
    @depend_on_related('SomeOtherModel')
    def some_computation(self):
       # your code
       return some_value
```

If this doesn't work I might personally use a custom sql then depending on django's ORM.

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't understand your suggestion. I think what you are suggesting is put the denormalization into each model in the path, is that what you are suggesting? So, it triggers the next level. I have thought of that, but the problem is I have django-auth's user model in between, which I don't want to touch.

Comment: Well you could try extending the Django auth user model and maybe make  your `CustomProfile(auth.User)` as the one referenced by the `Question` model